# How to stop propagation when using ng-repeat (or how to better isolate scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Noob question here I am trying to find the best way to set a scope variable inside of a ng-repeat. Since each index of the list will have the same scope variable, I am seeing changes to multiple rows when I only want one item's scope to be affected. What is the best way to handle this in angular? I have tried digging around for a few hours now, but I can't seem to get this working.

If you take a look at the plunker below you will see i am iterating over basic object array. I also have a ng-click setup so that when the user clicks on the item in the array it **should** show the long title and hide the short title for that item **only**. But as you can see it's also affect the second item in the array because of obvious reasons (they are both binded to the same $scope var).

What is the best way so that only the item that I select hides short title and shows the long title?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="myFunct(item)">

      <div ng-if="expanded == null">{{item.shortTitle}}</div>
      <p ng-if="expanded != null">{{item.longTitle}}</p>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>

var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
myApp.controller('MyCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{shortTitle: "short title 1", longTitle: "Long Title 1"},
  {shortTitle: "short title 2", longTitle: "Long Title 2"}];
  $scope.expanded = null;
  $scope.myFunct = function(item) {
    $scope.expanded = item;
  };

}]);
```

PLUNK: http://plnkr.co/edit/xWTDJF7S5wvtxFq5aakv?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add expanded as a boolean to the item instead of to scope. Then use a private variable to keep the previous expanded item which can then be collapsed:

```
var expandedItem;

$scope.myFunct = function(item) {
    if (expandedItem && expandedItem != item) {
        expandedItem.expanded = false;
    }
    expandedItem = item;
    item.expanded = !item.expanded;
};
```

```
<div ng-if="!item.expanded">{{item.shortTitle}}</div>
<p ng-if="item.expanded">{{item.longTitle}}</p>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ji34kokVS8hTXGN06h34?p=preview)

Comment: I do like this approach..... BUT is there anyway to extend it so that when item two is expanded it will close item one if it is **already** expanded?

Comment: That kind of works, but now i want to click on item.longTitle (again) and have it collapse back to to shortTitle. Currently your solution only toggles once.

Comment: One last question, a little more abstract... If you would be so kind. Lets say you wrapped the setting of the $scope.items inside of a $interval?   http://plnkr.co/edit/ieXULVmqpkDC8PIsrMVj?p=preview -- when you toggle the items (wait for it to show up...you can adjust the $interval if need be) - how would i then stop them from closing when the next $interval fires?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70506/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-dirkdigler).

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it via `this.expanded = item`, since `this` context will just be the child scope created by ng-repeat.

```
$scope.myFunct = function(item) {
 this.expanded = item;
};
```

If you want to be really explicit, then just pass in `ng-click="myFunct(item, this)"` and do:

```
$scope.myFunct = function(item, childScope) {
  childScope.expanded = item;
};
```

The reason behind passing `this` as ng-click argument is because every scope has a property called `this` which points to itself, and unlike passing `this` on events called via DOM, ng-click does not work that way, it evaluates arguments against the scope, so `scope[`this`] ==> scope`.

And ofcourse you could as well do:-

```
ng-click="expanded = item"
```

but it is better to isolate logic to your controller.