# ng-if and $interval when setting scope - weird behavior

Tags: angularjs

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389139/how-to-stop-propagation-when-using-ng-repeat-or-how-to-better-isolate-scope) Lets say you wrapped the setting of a $scope.items variable inside of a $interval?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="myFunct(item)">

      <div ng-if="!item.expanded">{{item.shortTitle}}</div>
      <p ng-if="item.expanded">{{item.longTitle}}</p>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Cntrl Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
myApp.controller('MyCntrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {

  $interval(function() {
      console.log("run");
      $scope.items = [{shortTitle: "short title 1", longTitle: "Long Title 1"},
        {shortTitle: "short title 2", longTitle: "Long Title 2"}];
    }, 1000);

  var expandedItem;

  $scope.myFunct = function(item) {
    if (expandedItem && expandedItem != item) {
        expandedItem.expanded = false;
    }
    expandedItem = item;
    item.expanded = !item.expanded;
  };

}]);
```

here is a plunker below with what I have setup:

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ieXULVmqpkDC8PIsrMVj?p=preview)

when you toggle the items (wait for it to show up...you can adjust the $interval if need be) - how would i then stop them from closing when the next $interval fires?

Comment: This is a contrived example but let's say you where making HTTP requests to gather data and need to set your $scope each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop though new loaded array and set expanded flag for corresponding item. I assume that items have some sort of id for easier identification. The modified code might look like this:

```
var expandedItem;

$interval(function() {

    $scope.items = [{
        id: 1,
        shortTitle: "short title 1",
        longTitle: "Long Title 1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        shortTitle: "short title 2",
        longTitle: "Long Title 2"
    }];

    if (expandedItem && expandedItem.expanded) {
        expandedItem = $scope.items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.id === expandedItem.id;
        })[0];
        expandedItem.expanded = true;
    }


}, 5000);

$scope.myFunct = function(item) {
    if (expandedItem && expandedItem.id !== item.id) {
        expandedItem.expanded = false;
    }
    expandedItem = item;
    item.expanded = !item.expanded;
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/qen4DU8O1jWeSsWO2p0s?p=preview

Note, that you can't compare `expandedItem == item` because those are different objects (even if they look the same). In this case you need to compare their ids.

Answer (score 1):

Every one sec you are resetting items to a new object(in which all items are collapsed). If you really want to keep your expanded item as expanded even after next data change, you should nt be overwriting items in $interval. May be check if items is not null and set items in $interval.

like this

```
 $interval(function() {
  console.log("run");
  if(!$scope.items) {
   $scope.items = [{shortTitle: "short title 1", longTitle: "Long Title 1"},
    {shortTitle: "short title 2", longTitle: "Long Title 2"}];
  }
}, 1000);
```

If you are simulating Ajax syncing of data, you should nt be overwriting the items with response, instead you should check if any new item is in this response and push that to $scope.items. Otherwise all state that you store in items object will be erased